# Freeform Pro - Writing an extension - How do I get form field values for validation?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am new to this so apologies to the noob question.

I am writing my first EE extension, for Freeform Pro. I have the basic shell working for freeform_module_validate_begin and have been able to Enable the extension and verify that it works when a form is being submitted.

What I am stumped by is how to find my form field values so I can perform custom validation. For example, if I have a form text field named 'panelist_name', how can I find that value when accessing the hook freeform_module_validate_begin so I can check it?

I've tried standard _POST and EE input post.

I assume this is a very simple issue, but I cannot find the answer so far in the docs, or in this forum.

Thanks
K.

Comment: This is really frustrating and confusing. The process I need is one of *validation* of data, but it seems the validation hooks only have error values. I'm not sure why that is, if so. I need to be able to analyze the form input data in the validation stage, before it proceeds to insert or notification. But I do not see anything in the docs about reading form input via this hook.

Comment: Can you not just read the $_POST array or ee()->input->post('variable_name')?

Comment: Yep. Sure enough it was that easy to read the value. ee()->input->post('variable_name') works for me. Thanks for the help... I figured this was a total novice oversight. I must have had some syntax wrong, since I had tried this method, or close to it, previously.